# After restarting the services, the impala tables are not coming up

Tags: hadoop, hive, impala

After restarting the Impala server, we are not able to see the tables(i.e. tables are not coming up).Anyone help me what order we have to follow to avoid this issue.

Thanks,
Srinivas

Answer (score 1):

You should try running "invalidate metadata;" from impala-shell.  This usually clears up tables not being visible as impala caches metadata.

From:
https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-8-x/topics/impala_invalidate_metadata.html

> The following example shows how you might use the INVALIDATE METADATA
>   statement after creating new tables (such as SequenceFile or HBase tables) through the Hive shell. Before the INVALIDATE METADATA statement was issued, Impala would give a "table not found" error if you tried to refer to those table names.